# How to disable second click of splitpane's one touch exapandable button in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, click, jsplitpane

I want to disable the second click option of `JSplitpane`'s one touch expandable button.

Is there any property to disable?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I tried the following method using `BasicSplitPaneDivider`

```
protected JButton createLeftOneTouchButton() {
    JButton left = super.createLeftOneTouchButton();
    left.setEnabled(true);
    // left.doClick(1);
    // left.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,600));
    return left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, no, there's no quick & easy way to do this. The buttons are created together in `BasicSplitPaneDivider`'s `oneTouchExpandableChanged()` method.

You could override this by creating your own implementation of `BasicSplitPaneDivider`, but then you get into the messy world of playing with the L&F.